# Не получается удалить данные из gridView SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, gridview, swiftui

Удаление происходит по нажатии на кнопку "Удалить" в alert

```
import SwiftUI

struct GridView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GridViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
    
    init() {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray6
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color(uiColor: .systemGray6)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: viewModel.items) {
                            ForEach(0..<listViewModel.lists.count, id: \.self) { index in
                                NavigationLink(destination: TasksListView(indexOfList: index)) {
                                    GridRowView(index: index)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: { viewModel.isAlertPresenting.toggle() }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .padding(.leading, 20)
                                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                            
                            Text("Новый список")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                        }
                        .alert("Новый список", isPresented: $viewModel.isAlertPresenting) {
                            TextField("Название", text: $viewModel.textFromAlert)
                            
                            Button("OK", role: .none) {
                                listViewModel.lists.append(
                                    TaskList(
                                        title: viewModel.textFromAlert,
                                        numberOfTasks: 0,
                                        colorOfImportant: .gray,
                                        isPrivate: false,
                                        tasks: []
                                    )
                                )
                                
                                viewModel.isAlertPresenting.toggle()
                                viewModel.textFromAlert = ""
                            }
                            
                            Button("Отмена", role: .cancel) {
                                viewModel.isAlertPresenting.toggle()
                                viewModel.textFromAlert = ""
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Simply Task")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            viewModel.isGridEditing.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(viewModel.isGridEditing ? .red : .gray)
                    }

                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .alert("Удалить список?", isPresented: $viewModel.isDeleteAlertPresenting) {
                Button("Отмена", role: .cancel) {
                    viewModel.isDeleteAlertPresenting.toggle()
                }
                
                Button("Удалить", role: .destructive) {
                    viewModel.isDeleteAlertPresenting.toggle()
                    listViewModel.deleteList(at: viewModel.selectedIndexForDelete)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GridView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GridView()
            .environmentObject(GridViewModel())
            .environmentObject(ListViewModel())
    }
}
```